# Basic R Webscraping - returning: character(0) error

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am just starting out learning R and have run into some problems when attempting my first non-tutorial attempt. I learned basic R through this tutorial: https://stat4701.github.io/edav/2015/04/02/rvest_tutorial/

I am trying to grab the review text and star rating from the item at this link: https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/4234190/detail.aspx?targetUrl

I created the following program to attempt at grabbing the two items that I want:

```
library('rvest')
review <- read_html("https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/4234190/detail.aspx?targetUrl")
body <- review %>% html_nodes(".body") %>% html_text()
body
rating <- review %>% html_nodes("#rating div") %>% html_attr("class")
rating
```

However the only things that this program returns is two instances of: character(0) and I have no idea how to go about solving this problem. This is such simple scraping that I am unsure how this doesn't work and I don't believe Javascript is the culprit because all of the reviews are loaded into hrml when the page is opened and not at a later point.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: JavaScript _is_ the issue, as if you look at the content you've scraped, the nodes you need are not there because they're loaded dynamically with JavaScript (which rvest can't run).

Comment: @alistaire How would you recommend moving forward? Is there a  solution/library/tutorial that you would recomend that would allow me to get these items?

Comment: splashr or RSelenium can grab the HTML, which you can then parse with rvest if you like.

Answer (score 0):

With the following R code, I was able to extract the ratings and reviews :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate('https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/4234190/detail.aspx?targetUrl')
remDr$executeScript("scroll(0, 5500)")
Sys.sleep(5)
page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

feedback_Rating <- str_extract_all(string = page_Content, pattern = "\\<span.class..feedback__rating(.*)\\</span\\>")[[1]]
feedback_Text <- str_extract_all(string = page_Content, pattern = "\\<p.class..feedback__text.*([:space:]|).*([:space:]|).*(|\\n)\\</p\\>")[[1]]
```